# Routing with mvc paging helper while using in 2 controller and a few action links

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have made an mvc paging helper and I need to use it in a few action links 
(different subjects  and different controller ) 
I'm stuck in the routing system ( I have no idea how to pass it )
This is my pager  helper :

```
enter code here public static string PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html , int currentPage,int totalPages ,Func<int,string> pageUrl)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++)
        {
            TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
            tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));
            tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
            if (i == currentPage)
                tag.AddCssClass("Selected");
            result.AppendLine(tag.ToString());
        }
        return result.ToString();

    }
```

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are asking but if it is how to call this helper here's how it might look like:

```
<%= Html.PageLinks(
    1, 
    10,
    p => Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController", new { page = p })
) %>
```

Comment: Well, first thanks, I know how to call the pager( <%=Html.PageLinks((int)ViewData["CurrentPage"], (int)ViewData["TotalPages"], x => Url.Action("morevorts", new { page = x }))%>) , I don’t know how to cofiger the call in the routing (the global.aspx)

Comment: @Izeq, the call is done in the view. I don't understand what call you want to configure and what relation does it have with routes?

Comment: The routing should let the site be faster (as the IIS do need to figer out the url's ) think about samthing like this (I'm New to mvc so try to folow my thinking (and i could be wrong about it )new { page = @"\d+" } as adding this to the routing Sys.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the following to you Global.asax

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                          "any name",
                          "ControllerName/Page/{page}",
                          new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "Index" }
                      );
```